# Twitter api key says unknown key

Tags: javascript, twitter-oauth, twitter-login

I have downloaded source code from below site
http://oauth-io.github.io/oauth-js/

and implemented for twitter as-is.
but when I intialize with my app consumer key it returns unknown key, where as when I give consumer key form demo source code, it works, what setting I need.

```
function twitterLogin()
    {
        console.log(OAuth);
        OAuth.initialize('xxxxxx');
        OAuth.popup('twitter', function (error, success) {
            console.log('error ' + error);
            console.log('success ' + success);
        });

}
```

It just says unknown key and popup closed immediately.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using your OAuth.io app **public** key?

Comment: I am using the  api key generated in twitter developer account for app

Comment: I didn't see any public key there

Comment: Use your OAuth key in `OAuth.initialize('xxxxxx');` not the twitter key

Comment: First make sure you have created an API on Twitter. Link: https://dev.twitter.com. Then get the `public key` you got from the API and paste that in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [OAuth.io Docs](http://docs.oauth.io/#install-the-sdk):

> When you create an OAuth.io application in your dashboard, a pair of
>   public key, private key is generated. You will need this pari to
>   initialize the SDK later on.

```
// Initialize the SDK
OAuth.initialize('Your-public-key')
```

> To authorize your app using OAuth.io, you just need to add a provider
>   to your OAuth.io app, copy/paste your provider’s API Keys (usually
>   client_id and client_secret), and specify a permission scope. Then,
>   you can directly try a connection to the provider, by clicking on the
>   Try auth button.
>
> You can also use the Token API to sign up your users with their social
>   identity. provider is the name of a provider on OAuth.io as facebook,
>   twitter, google and 100+ others.
>
> The provider needs to have the User API enabled to work properly (you
>   can see it when you add a new provider in your OAuth.io Dashbaord).

This is important. Your Twitter API Key goes into your OAuth.io Dashboard and your OAuth.io Key goes into your initialize function.

Comment: does it mean we have to take license from OAuth.io ?